# Why linked object property is not working on this query?

Tags: ios, realm

Why this query is throwing that presentations is not a property of `PresentationSpeaker`?

```
var result = realm.objects(PresentationSpeaker.self).sorted(sortProperties)

if searchTerm != nil && !(searchTerm!.isEmpty) {
    result = result.filter("fullName CONTAINS [c]%@ or ANY presentations.event.name CONTAINS [c]%@ ", searchTerm!, searchTerm!)
}
```

Entity definition

```
public class PresentationSpeaker: Person {
    public var presentations: [Presentation] {
        return linkingObjects(Presentation.self, forProperty: "speakers")
    } 
}
```

Isn't it possible to use linked objects in queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Queries on computed properties are not supported. Currently there's no way to query based on incoming links to an object; [work on adding that is in progress](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1324).